# facebook share not fetching og:image

Tags: image, facebook, share, meta-tags

I have added FB share dialog to share images on facebook. I have tried all possible solutions but its still not fetching image. After sometime for some posts it works but not most of the times.

I have forcefully scraped the urls using php curl

```
$current_url = get_permalink();
    $curl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/';
    $return = getCurlRequest($curl,'id='http://viralsyndicator.com/best-spring-fishing-lures-of-2018-bass-pro-shops-challenge/'&scrape=true&access_token=token');

    function getCurlRequest($url,$postdata=""){ 
      //echo $url;
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:','Content-Type: application/json'));  
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10000);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $response  = curl_exec($ch);
      //echo '<pre>';print_r($response);
      curl_close($ch);  
      if ($response == false){ return false;}
      return $response;
    }
```

This page always has og:image meta tag but still it does not work. When I go to fb debugger tool and I debug it, first time it says og:image should be provided, scraping it after 2-3 times it starts working.

I have tried og:image:width properties as well.

I am using wordpress plugin to share, I have used FB.ui as well manually and it worked for sharing but I am also using FB comment plugin and when I am commenting and checking checkbox to post on fb as well, its not publishing image and I don't know how to use FB comment plugin manually similarly share to fetch correct image instead of logo.

```
FB.ui({
                        method: 'share',
                        href: '<?php echo $postUrl; ?>',
                        picture: "http://viralsyndicator.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/0-199-670x377_c.jpg",
                        title: 'title',
                        description: '<?php echo $decodedPostTitle; ?>',

                    }, function(response) {});
```

I dont know how to solve this FB issue.Please help guys.

Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/: _“Object at URL '...' of type 'website' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values”_

Comment: @CBroe there is only one og:url on this page, I just debugged url on this tool this time it is not showing any error, you try it now

Comment: Once on line #29, and then again on #115.

Comment: @CBroe by mistake just activated one more plugin thats why coming twice but the issue is still the same for other urls like I just created new post http://viralsyndicator.com/dragon-ball-super-capitulo-130-avance-dbs-sub-espa-ol-latino-hd/

Comment: Why, what exactly is not working now? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fviralsyndicator.com%2Fdragon-ball-super-capitulo-130-avance-dbs-sub-espa-ol-latino-hd%2F

Comment: @CBroe try to click on fb share button on the page,it does not fetch image until I scrape it from debugger tool. While I am already using scraping via php code. Try other url now e.g http://viralsyndicator.com/gastei-r-500-em-coisas-da-china-e-esse-foi-o-resultado/